# Strange Javascript behavior - js object

Tags: javascript, boolean, javascript-objects

I want to code some sort of state machine with different transitions. But something strange happens, when I want to select an item.

```
var transitions = {
    "on": {
        "false":"true",
        "true":"false"
    }
}
```

The last two lines are very interresting - the same index, first `hardcoded` and the second stored within a variable. Why does the first return the right result (false) and the other undefined?

```
console.log(attr);                             // on
console.log(transitions[attr]);                // Object { false="true, true="false" }
console.log(current_val);                      // "true"
console.log(typeof current_val);               // string
console.log(transitions[attr]["true"]);        // false
console.log(transitions[attr][current_val]);   // undefined
```

*info: I use FF 14.0.1*

Comment: If `console.log(current_val);` produces `"true"` then it seems `current_val` must be set to `'"true"'`, since `console.log` should not print quotes.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5xKhH/). Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure, but using reserved words like that is asking for trouble ;) Still a good question though

Comment: @nneonneo Smart. You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: interesting sidenote (regarding chrome): running the code in an html page (or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dc8aU/)) gives the desired output, running it completely in the console gives the described output (e.g. `undefined` for the last row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `console.log(current_val);` outputs `"true"` to the console. Since `console.log` doesn't print quotes, it must be the case that `current_val` contains `'"true"'`, which isn't the same as `"true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the fact that true is not evaluated to string in the last statement.

Comment: why not? typeof returns string?! ... How can I cast it to one? `console.log(transitions[attr][String(current_val)]);` doesn't work.